# Export/Import Data Pump when tablespace is in different path

Tags: oracle, datapump

I need to do an export data pump of schema TESTE from server A and import on server B (OS Linux).

I pre-created a tablespace in server B but in server B, I have ASM. My question is, can I have some problem during import, like "tablespace not found" since the tablespace path is different from tablespace path in server A.

How the data during the import goes to the created tablespace and does not occur the error "the tablespace not found"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any issues.  We always import (impdp/expdp) from server A to B where the tablespaces have entirely different names and paths across servers.